# Can I redirect to a new php file while posting a form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, post

I have a html web page which I use to get some user input. This input is then posted using jquery to a php script which in turn sends a get request to a REST API to receive json data.

My question really is: is it possible to change my php file into another webpage with embedded php and redirect to this while posting the variables to the same script, so I could display the json results in a table on a new page simultaneously.

I already receive the json in the javascript file and I know I could use this to create a table, I was just interested if I could in fact do it all in one go on the php page as I already have script written to populate a table using the json data.

I have included some basic fragments of my code to help explain what I am doing.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="collect_User_Input.js"></script>
</head>
<p> What is the unique id of the beacon? </p> 
<form> <input type="text" id="uniqueId" /> </form> 
<button onclick="collect_User_Input();" >Send Request</button>
```

JS:

```
var uniqueId = document.getElementById('uniqueId');
$.post("send_Request.php", { uniqueId: uniqueId.value },function(result) {
alert(result);
```

PHP:

```
$uniqueId = $_POST["uniqueId"];
```

(GET request using curl)

```
 echo ($uniqueId);
```

I tried skipping the javascript step and submitting the form directly, but this always gave me forbidden error messages. as you may have guessed I am very new to this so any advice is welcome.

Comment: you can change the location of the page with `window.location`.

Comment: Or with PHP using header("Location: page.html");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP you will most likely want to return some JSON using json_encode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Within your JSON, you could return a success value - then depending on the value of that you can redirect using:

```
window.location
```

You could even have a second attribute that returns what page you want the user redirected to if it isn't the same as the uniqueID:

```
{"success":true,"location":"/your/path/here.html"}
```

The flip side being, if there is an error you can return this to your page with a relevant message:

```
{"success":false,"message":"ID not found"}
```

I use this process to check something is valid on the server before doing the redirect, which sounds more or less the same as what you want to do?

Comment: Also, have you tried running a 'hello world' style PHP script to make sure your PHP is actually accessible to you? Have you tried accessing your script by typing it into the browser to see if it errors? Also, if you have access to them, take a look at the PHP logs to see if there are errors there.